# htaccess regex for number greater than 1?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule to match data-2, data-3, data-4 etc. and send them to data.php?var=2. It needs to ignore data-1.

```
RewriteRule ^data-([2-9])/?$ index.php?page=data&var=$1 [NC,L]
```

The above rule works for numbers 2-9, but how can I make it so that it works for any number greater than 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^data-([2-9]|[1-9]\d+)/?$ index.php?page=data&var=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^data-([2-9]|[1-9]\d+)/?$ index.php?page=data&var=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks (same answer at the same time must mean it's the best solution ;) )